# Change mintty title according active tmux window (cygwin)

Tags: cygwin, tmux, mintty

How can I change mintty terminal title to show title of active tmux window?

For example:

[image]

I would like in this case title to be active tmux window - `ncmpcpp` or even better if possible title provided by running program in active window, in this example - `Steve Roach - A Deepe`, instead current title `-bash`?